# Is it possible to automatically convert javascript to closure template format?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-templates

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert javascript to closure template format without having to manually add all of the closure tags/formatting:

```
{namespace example.templates}
/** 
*@param var1 Description
*@param var2 Description
*/
```

From my understanding, we need to write javascript with this formatting before it's compiled into a .soy file.

Comment: what javscript do you wish to convert? using esprima you could parse the js and generate the soy files.

Comment: ideally i'd like to parse javascript/jquery from some of the free widgets found online. would this also parse html/css if I included everything in the same file? for example: mywidget.html   with the <style> and <script> tags + content included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using {literal} javascript here {/literal} was a decent work around as the code inside the literal tags doesn't get parsed.